# How can I save each iteration of a variable inside a for loop?

Tags: java

I have my variable part1 and for each iteration of the for loop i want to take part1s value and save it to use it later.

Im not sure how to make this happen.

```
for (int i : list) {
        part1 = i - average(list);
    }
```

Comment: I assume you have heard of 'lists'? seeing as you use one already, I guess you do. store your values in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use List

**Import ArrayList**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

**Initialize List**

```java
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**Add elements to List:**

```java
myList.add(part1);
```

**Code:**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int part1;
        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

        int[] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        for (int i : list) {
            part1 = i - average(list);
            myList.add(part1);
        }
    }
}
```

As suggested by [stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636929/stultuske) in the comments, follow the current standards

**Updated Code:**

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int part1;
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(); 

        int[] list = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        for (int i : list) {
            part1 = i - average(list);
            myList.add(part1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Update datatype of `list` depending on your use-case

Comment: preferably, use up to date standards and program against interfaces. Change:
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
into 
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();